# Are increment operators in Go atomic on x86?

Tags: concurrency, thread-safety, go, atomic

Here's some background:
I need a counter variable shared between go routines, used for something like a leaky-bucket. I know there's an example of leaky-bucket in Effective Go, concurrent section, but the number that I need to track may be very large, and I feel it's inefficient to use number of elements in a channel to track it. So I am considering of using a shared variable between different routines to track the number.

I understand that without explicit configuration, all go routines are mapped onto one thread. But if I assign more than one thread to the program on a multi-core computer, is increment operators atomic? Is it all the same for different data types (`int32`, `float32`, etc.) on different machines (`x86_32`, `x86_64`, `arm`)?

To be more concrete, What if I have `counter += 1000` in one routine, and `counter -= 512` in another routine, and the two routines happens to be running in two threads? Do I need to worry about thread-safty? Shall I put on locks on the `counter`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, increment should never be assumed to be atomic. Use the atomic addition functions or a mutex.

Lets assume:

```
import "sync/atomic"
var counter = new(int32)
```

One goroutine could do `atomic.AddInt32(counter, 1000)` while another did `atomic.AddInt32(counter, -512)` without a mutex.

If you would rather use a mutex:

```
import "sync"
var counter int32
var mutex sync.Mutex

func Add(x int32) {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    counter += x
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I didn't notice there's `sync/atomic`. That makes things much easier!